# Can I escape the Gmail "Apply Label" box with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gmail

I sometimes want to apply a label but then change my mind. I have found that the only way to escape the dialog box is by mouse clicking somewhere outside of it because the Escape key doesn't work.

Does anyone know of a workaround for this because it really breaks my keyboard-shortcuts-only workflow.

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts for Gmail **[Link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)**

Comment: @Biswa Thanks. I use them all the time and in particular I use the 'l' for 'Open "label as"' under the Application shortcuts to open up the labelling window. However I haven't found a way anywhere for how to close that dialog again if you don't want to select a label.